# Using JWT token to create spring session

Tags: rest, spring, jwt

I have a web application like this:

[image: Application Setup]

An angular frontend for client and a spring MVC backend for admin panel.

1. A angular web application requests a JWT token from tomcat/spring MVC.
2. The angular application the uses the token as Bearer for HTTP requests.

But now a requirement has come up:

1. The user will use that token to log in into the spring web application.
2. The server will verify that token to create a session in the backend.

My question is, is the setup feasible, are there any security risks associated with using a JWT token to authenticate in spring mvc backend?

Comment: There is no issue if you are just using the token for authentication. Authorization is more complicated. Is an authenticated user restricted or is that sufficient to access your back-end?

Comment: I am using the token only for authentication. But, I am only authenticating  the user using the token once (spring has already created the session).